# Ошибка:Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00246198 в Dz_c++_5.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x004F0000

Tags: c++

> Программа писалась для сортировки чисел(в порядке убывания)
>   [image: код в visual studio]

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "rus");
const int n = 10000;
int mass[n];
int len,temp;

cout << "Размер=";
cin >> len;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cout << "["<<i<<"]=";
    cin >> mass[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; i < len; j++) {
        if (mass[i] < mass[j]) {//ошибка здесь
            temp = mass[i];
            mass[i] = mass[j];
            mass[j] = temp;
        }

    }

}

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    cout << "[" << i << "]=" << mass[i] << endl;
}

cout << "\n";
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Вангую выход за пределы массива.

Comment: в `for (int j = i+1; i < len; j++)` опечатка, должно быть `for (int j = i+1; j < len; j++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for (int j = i+1; i < len; j++)` - выход за пределы массива. `j` -> в бесконечность.

Comment: бленб, банальная не внимательность, забыл изменить i на j (нужно меньше использовать ctr+v), спасибо